# What kind of data is a date (adding data to a chart) visual basic

Tags: vb.net, date, mschart

I am trying to load my date into the x axis of my chart in VB 2O10 and I am not sure what kind of data a date would be? String, Integer etc?

**Here's the code that I have:**

```
dtTest.Columns.Add("Mark", GetType(Integer))
dtTest.Columns.Add("dateTime", GetType('"Need Data type for Date Here"'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `Date` will work

```
GetType(Date)
```

and then I add `Cht.Series(0).XValueType = ChartValueType.Date` to make sure the x axis formats as a date as well

Answer (score 0):

Internally MSChart handles `DateTime` as `double`, using the OLE Automation Date format. You can convert to and from this format using `DateTime.ToOADate` and `DateTime.FromOADate` functions. so for example you may add a point dated now with this code:

```
mySeries.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), a_Y_value);
```